# How do I evaluate an edn/read list?

Tags: clojure, eval, clojurescript, edn

```clj
(def a (edn/read-string "(+ 1 3)"))
; => (+ 1 3)
```

How do I evaluate this resulting list?

```clj
(type (first a))
; => cljs.core/Symbol

(= (first a) '+)
; => true
```

I suppose more generally how would I get from symbol -> function.
And is this a normal practice in clojure? I can't seem to find anything on it. Perhaps I'm not searching with the correct terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer seems to only work in Clojure, not ClojureScript. See the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55997055/3000206).

---

I think you may be looking for [`resolve`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/resolve).

```
(defn my-simple-eval [expr]
  ; Cut the function symbol from the arguments
  (let [[f & args] (edn/read-string expr)]
    ; Resolve f to a function then apply the supplied arguments to it 
    (apply (resolve f) args)))

(my-simple-eval "(+ 1 3)")
=> 4
```

The arguments must be bare numbers for this to work though. If you want to allow for sub-expressions, you could make it recursive:

```
(defn my-simple-eval-rec [expr]
  (letfn [(rec [[f & args]]
            (->> args
                 (map (fn [arg]
                        (if (list? arg)
                          (rec arg) ; Process the sub-expr
                          arg)))

                 (apply (resolve f))))]

    (rec (edn/read-string expr))))

(my-simple-eval-rec "(+ 1 (+ 2 5))")
=> 8
```

If this doesn't suffice though, I don't know of any way other than using `eval`:

```
(def a (edn/read-string "(+ 1 3)"))

(eval a)
=> 4
```

or, if the data is available at the time macros are expanded, you could just wrap the call to `read-string` to have the data interpreted as normal:

```
(defmacro my-read-string [expr]
  (edn/read-string expr))

(my-read-string "(+ 1 3)")
=> 4
```

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks for the answers. So it looks like I've been working in a cljs repl. These work in a normal repl.

This is what I get when using resolve on the symbol in cljs:
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo :
    java.lang.AssertionError : Assert failed: Argument to resolve must be a quoted symbol
(core/and (seq? quoted-sym) (= (quote quote) (first quoted-sym)))

Comment: @koboldsinparis Honestly, I don't know  ClojureScript. I can try to look into it in the morning.

Answer (score 5):

You'd normally use `eval`. But in ClojureScript, you'd need the compiler and standard lib available at runtime. This is only possible if you are making use of self-hosted ClojureScript.

If you are in a self-hosted environment (such as Lumo, Planck, Replete, Klipse, *etc.*), then `eval` will just work:

```
cljs.user=> (require '[clojure.edn :as edn])
nil
cljs.user=> (def a (edn/read-string "(+ 1 3)"))
#'cljs.user/a
cljs.user=> (eval a)
4
```

Otherwise, you can make use of the facilities in the `cljs.js` namespace to access self-hosted ClojureScript:

```
cljs.user=> (require 'cljs.js)
nil
cljs.user=> (cljs.js/eval (cljs.js/empty-state)
  a {:eval cljs.js/js-eval :context :expr} prn)
{:value 4}
```

> Note that doing this carries some size considerations: The ClojureScript compiler will be brought with your compiled artifacts into the target environment, and you must also avoid using `:advanced`, ensuring that the entire `cljs.core` standard lib and associated metadata is available at runtime.